# Scrapy splash - Refused connection

Tags: docker, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I have an issue with Splash when running my web crawler. First when I run `docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash` in docker I get this (I use docker toolbox as I'm working on Windows 10 home):

```
2019-05-16 15:21:49+0000 [-] Log opened.
2019-05-16 15:21:49.752049 [-] Splash version: 3.3.1
2019-05-16 15:21:49.753669 [-] Qt 5.9.1, PyQt 5.9.2, WebKit 602.1, sip 4.19.4, Twisted 18.9.0, Lua 5.2
2019-05-16 15:21:49.753925 [-] Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
2019-05-16 15:21:49.754147 [-] Open files limit: 1048576
2019-05-16 15:21:49.754467 [-] Can't bump open files limit
2019-05-16 15:21:49.860067 [-] Xvfb is started: ['Xvfb', ':1506361592', '-screen', '0', '1024x768x24', '-nolisten', 'tcp']
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
2019-05-16 15:21:49.958484 [-] proxy profiles support is enabled, proxy profiles path: /etc/splash/proxy-profiles
2019-05-16 15:21:49.958882 [-] memory cache: enabled, private mode: enabled, js cross-domain access: disabled
2019-05-16 15:21:50.108753 [-] verbosity=1, slots=20, argument_cache_max_entries=500, max-timeout=90.0
2019-05-16 15:21:50.110291 [-] Web UI: enabled, Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled)
2019-05-16 15:21:50.111203 [-] Site starting on 8050
2019-05-16 15:21:50.111508 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7fc868f8dcc0>
2019-05-16 15:21:50.112315 [-] Server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8050
```

I've correctly set the middlewares and others in my settings.py:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

However when I run my crawler I get this log:

```
2019-05-16 17:35:10 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://localhost:8050/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): Connection was refused by other side: 10061: Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée..
2019-05-16 17:35:11 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://localhost:8050/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): Connection was refused by other side: 10061: Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée..
2019-05-16 17:35:12 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://localhost:8050/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): Connection was refused by other side: 10061: Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée..
2019-05-16 17:35:12 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://localhost:8050/robots.txt>: Connection was refused by other side: 10061: Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\coppe\Anaconda3\envs\scrapyEnv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 10061: Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée..
```

Sorry some part is in french but basically says that the targeted computer has explicitly refused the connection. I guess something went wrong with docker because when I search for `http://localhost:8050`in my web browser I get nothing (connection failed).

Does someone can help me with this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the [robots.txt setting](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey)?

Comment: Not working I think it's an issuer with VirtualBox but I'll try to do things differently. Thanks for the help !